# How to order by multiple columns with different priority for each column?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, database-performance

Let's assume a `users` table like:

```
 age  | popularity
------------------
  16  |     2
  23  |     5
  17  |     2
  16  |     3
 ...  |    ...
 ...  |    ...
```

I want to select rows with smaller age and bigger popularity. But not to choose the one over the other.

With:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
ORDER BY `age` ASC, `popularity` DESC
```

We will have the younger users on top and the users with the same `age` would be ordered by popularity among themselves.

And with:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
ORDER BY `popularity` DESC, `age` ASC
```

We will have the most popular users on top and the users with the same `popularity` ordered by `age` among themselves.

But I do not want to choose the one sorting over the other. I want to mix them up.

**How do I achieve sorting with 60% based on `popularity` and 40% based on `age`?**

Is there a general-purpose solution for such sorting? Is a custom function the only option?

**UPDATE**: Sample desired results

```
 age  | popularity
------------------
  16  |     8
  15  |     2
  23  |     5
  29  |    10
  16  |     3
  16  |     2
  17  |     2
```

So if a user is very young she should be higher even with smaller popularity. If a user is quite popular she should be higher even if she is older.

The most young and most popular should be always on top. The most old and the least popular should be always on the bottom.

**I am looking for a general-purpose solution, not just for numbers, but for dates, strings and so on.**

Comment: @JohnWoo sample results added and explained a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select *, priority*0.6+age*0.4 as sortkey from ... order by sortkey.
```

Comment: Would this be able to use an index for the query?

Comment: No, if you want to use an index you have to add a new field for storing this value.

Comment: @Bohdan actually storing such value in a separate field makes much sense. I would be able to update with a background process or a cronjob and have both the correct sorting and better performance. :-)

Comment: @HaralanDobrev It denormalizes the database. If you want to do it that way, define a view.